# Visual Studio 2019 loses focus when editing code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS 2019 for Unity development, and sometimes when I'm writing code, my input randomly dissapears.

Example:

I'm typing:

```
private
```

but in the editor after I typed

```
pr
```

My other keyboard input dissapears and I have to click inside the editor to fix it. This bug is driving me crazy so I hope someone also had this and found a solution for it.

Comment: Run with /safemode - if that fixes it it's an extension at fault so start disabling them until you find the culprit

Comment: will try it ty :)

Comment: It was new perforce plugin fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by an extension as @Alex K. mentioned. (Perforce not yet made a vs 2019 plugin)

Update they made one.